# how to compile multiple files together when one of them is a Linux Kernel module

Tags: c, module

There are several files in my folder:
**module.c** , **uart.c** , **uart.h** .

In the file **module.c** I have `#include "uart.h"`.

How do I make a makefile?
regular makefile:

```
obj-m := module.o
KERNELDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
echo "bulding module for intel architecture:"
```

when I execute **make** on the *makefile* above, it gives me an error that it does not know the functions from *uart.c*, although I have *include* in the code

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "one of them is a module".

Comment: Oh, you mean a Linux kernel module.

Comment: in `#include uart.h` _`uart.h`_ needs to be surrounded by either `"..."` or `<...>`.

Comment: @ryyker
yes, sure. I have `#include "uart .h"`

Comment: Is the kernel module to be built using code from all three .c files? If so, then the base name of the built module cannot be the same as any of the .c files.

Comment: Please do not show different code in your question than you are trying to use. See the concept of making a [mre].

Comment: no not all just uart .c and uart .h

Comment: The Linux kernel build system will set the dependencies on header files automatically.

Comment: @IanAbbott no. when I execute **make** on the _makefile_ above, it gives me an error that it does not know the functions from _uart.c_, although I have _include_ in the code

Comment: Are you trying to build one module (.ko file) containing code from both **module.c** and **uart.c**, or are you trying to build two modules **module.ko** and **uart.ko**?

Comment: @IanAbbott to build one module (.ko file) containing code from both module.c and uart.c,

Comment: @IanAbbott  uart.c it contains the usual computational functions not related to the kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a Linux kernel module from two (or more) .c files, **module.c** and **uart.c**:

```kbuild
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

obj-m := mymodule.o
mymodule-objs := module.o uart.o

else

KERNELDIR ?= "/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build"

all:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KERNELDIR)" M="$(CURDIR)" modules

install:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KERNELDIR)" M="$(CURDIR)" modules_install

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KERNELDIR)" M="$(CURDIR)" clean

endif
```

The above will build a module named **mymodule.ko**. For kernel modules composed of more than one object file (**module.o** and **uart.o** in this case), the name of the built module object file (**mymodule.o** in this case) must be different from the names of the component object files.

Comment: Thanks! and if the original has one more gpio_module.c file and I want to get gpio_module.ko module.ko separately (I need to have two modules and one of them consists of several C files)

Comment: @Yael Then either change `obj-m := mymodule.o` to `obj-m := mymodule.o gpio_module.o`, or add a line `obj-m += gpio_module.o` after the `obj-m :=` line. If gpio_module.ko is composed of several .c files (e.g. foo1.c, foo2.c and foo3.c), add a line similar to `gpio_module-objs := foo1.o foo2.o foo3.o` to set the names of the component object files for that module.